# How do I find the min and max predicted probability of a hurdle model?

Tags: r

Update: I used the following code:

```
 predict(h15, type = "zero")
```

When I do this the min=.2540 and max=136.9599
The max doesn't make sense because we are talking about probability. Can someone explain this to me please?

I need to find the min and max predicted probability of a hurdle model?
I have provided my code and a picture of what I get. From here I am unsure how to find the min and max probability of having any derogatory marks against one’s credit, among those sampled.

```
 library(AER)
 cc <- CreditCard
 newcc <- cc[c(-79, -324, -435, -462, -656, -659, -1195),]
 h15 <- hurdle(reports ~ share + owner + active | share + owner +
            months + active , data = newcc, dist = "negbin")
 summary(h15)
```

[image: hurdle_model]

Comment: According to the docs on `predict.hurdle(...)` using `type='zero'` provides the ratio of the probability of a 0 to a probability of a non-zero count. So this could easily be > 1.

Answer (score 0):

"*From here I am unsure how to find the min and max probability of having any derogatory marks against one’s credit, among those sampled.*"

So assuming the `reports` column in `CreditCard` records the number of derogatory remarks,

```
pred.matrix <- predict(h15, type = "prob")
```

produces a matrix (n rows X 15 columns) containing the probabilities of each possible outcome (0 - 14 in this case) for each of the n cases. The first column is the probability of 0 reports. So,

```
range(rowSums(pred.matrix[, -1]))
## [1] 0.00192127 0.71549271
```

produces the range (min and max) of the sum of the probabilities of an outcome > 0, for each case.